# Xrandr command in startup script has no effect, but script does run and command work from terminal

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, xrandr, autostart, lxqt

I cannot seem to get an xrandr command to rotate my monitor at startup.

The script:

```
cat /etc/X11/Xsession.d/999_test                                                                                                     
xrandr --output DVI-D-3 --off --output HDMI-3 --off --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate left --output DVI-D-2-1 --off --output DP-2-1 --off --output DP-2-2 --off --output HDMI-2-1 --off --output DP-2-3 --off --output DisplayPort-1-3 --off --output DisplayPort-1-4 --off --output DisplayPort-1-5 --off --output HDMI-A-1-1 --off --output DVI-D-1-1 --off

xclock &
```

and the script itself is working, because if I add `xclock &` to the end of the script, I start my session with xclock lauched, but my screen not rotated (until I run the command from the terminal)

After logging in, if I run

```
 sh /etc/X11/Xsession.d/999_test
```

It works exactly as expected, rotating my monitor and opening xclock.

I don't see any errors related to xrandr or my script name in `~/.xsession-errors`. Is that where I would expect to find them?
I am using Lubuntu 20.04

Edit: As I had been using LXDE before, which has less advanced monitor management, I thought I needed to run this. Even though I do not need to, I'd still like to figure out why this didn't work. I thought that by naming it starting with `999` my script would be executed last and thus not be overridden by anything else.

Comment: You mention Lubuntu at the end of your question text, but Lubuntu uses LXQt, and you tagged LXDE; are you using LXDE or LXQt?  *Lubuntu monitor settings can be changed via https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html but it won't impact `sddm` or text terminals*

Comment: Sorry, I am just using regular Lubuntu, I have updated the tags to reflect that, and I do see the setting in monitors, but I'd still like to know why this startup script isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use the 'autostart' feature of LXQt.

- From the Main Menu

  - select Settings

    - select LXQt Configuration Center
- select Session Settings

  - select Autostart

    - scroll down to and high-light 'LXQT Autostart'
- click the Add button and add the action that you want.

This way you will create a desktop file in the directory

```
~/.config/autostart
```

When testing, I created `screenmode.desktop`. You can see it and the result, after logging out and logging in again in this screenshot:

[image]

Good luck with your longer and more advanced command line :-)

Comment: Nicely formatted answer.