# Autostart issues running simple xrandr script on start up

Tags: display-resolution, startup, xrandr, 21.04, autostart

I've created a simple startup script so that I can use my Ultrawide Monitor with Ubuntu 21.04 (should be similar with the previous version as well).  However when I configured this script to be run on startup using 'Autostart' I get an error upon startup instead with the script unable to run.  **Manually running the script works fine** - It's a pain to run it on every start manually....

Anyhow I get this error:

```
Warning: Could not start program '/home/user/scripts/2560x1080.sh' with arguments '/home/user/scripts/2560x1080.sh'.

Warning: execve: Exec format error
```

**Also**, here's the simple script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#cd /home/user/scripts/
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00" 230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
```

**Thanks** *in advance*

Comment: Have you tried chronjobs to initialize this script?

Comment: Maybe these links: [link 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353879/lubuntu-20-04-run-a-script-at-login-which-executes-in-a-terminal-window/1354182#1354182) and [link 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251814/xrandr-command-in-startup-script-has-no-effect-but-script-does-run-and-command/1251882#1251882) can help you. The method is tested on verson 20.04 LTS of Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the crontab suggestion!  Adding "@reboot sleep 10 && /home/user/scripts/2560x1080.sh" (no quotes) to the end of crontab didn't work and didn't provide an error message so I have no idea what went a rye :[  This is actually on KDE or Kubuntu...

Comment: Are you trying to run the script on *startup* or on *login*?

Comment: I'm trying to run this on startup.  I just want the monitor to work on it's native ultrawide resolution on startup.  Am I creating a new "startscript.sh" that runs my 2562x1080.sh script that crontab will run?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a cronjob yet?

You can use crontab for this:

```
crontab -e
```

At the bottom of the file you can add an item to run at reboot:

EG:

```
@reboot /home/{your user}/scripts/startscript.sh
```

Note: This may run before all of dependencies load. You may want to run the shell script asychronously (eg using  & in bash) and add a sleep time to your shell script.

Note: You may want to play around with permissions a bit depending on if you want to run with sudo.

Note: `sudo crontab -e` is different than `crontab -e`

Edit:

To add logging to your startscript.sh you can try piping the output of commands to a log file like this:
`/home/user/scripts/startscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Source your bashrc for environment variables
# Note this uses . as source (old school unix) 
# because the source command might not be available depending on the OS
. /home/user/.bashrc
sleep 30
echo "Starting Log" > /home/user/scripts/log.txt
/home/user/scripts/myscript.sh >> /home/user/scripts/log.txt
```

Note: Paths should be absolute in chronjobs.

Comment: Did you try to run [a script with] `xrandr` from `crontab @reboot`? A script with `xrandr` works for me from `autostart`.