# Adding an autostart feature to an existing install using USB stick

Tags: autostart

I have a set of touch panels (30pcs) that come pre installed with Lubuntu, and I want to add an autostart feature:
''/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --disk-cache-size=1 [http://192.168.42.1/''](http://192.168.42.1/%27%27)
As soon as I start Googling for "Ubuntu autostart" I get led down the wrong path. I just want a bash command to add this command to the autostart in our touchpanels. I have formatted the USB stick in question to ext4, just need to know where to start looking for a bash command that will let me add something to autostart in (L)Ubuntu.
The instruction I got from R&D include "vi filename etc etc, then press  I to insert etc etc" but doing this 30 times over is going to be boooring, and thus I ask if there is a simpler way, using "autorun.sh"? CLI is fun, but not THAT fun, especially not 30 times over.
Second part of the question would be how to disable certain already enabled autostart features(blueman, which we don't use anyway).

I'm happy to start reading up on it, if I just get a good starting point.

Thanks in advance,
Freudlund

Comment: what is "autostart"? Do you want a cron job or systemd timer that does this? You can also just write a bash command that edits a text file (which is what vi does, of course)

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251814/xrandr-command-in-startup-script-has-no-effect-but-script-does-run-and-command/1251882#1251882) will help you create a desktop file, that you can copy to the 30 touch panels. I think it is almost as easy to copy the desktop file to the directory `~/.config/autostart` as to create a batch file that will do it, anyway both ways are possible and using the batch file is less boring :-P - But if the touch panels are not yet preinstalled, you can create a complete master system, create an image of it and clone it to the other 29 touch panels.